# Keep a button centered over an fluid image

Tags: html, css, compass-sass

The last few days i tried to center a button over a fluid image. So far the position is fixed and static. The relevant HTML part looks like the following:

```
<ul class="moodlegrid sectionwrap">
  <li>
    <a class="ajax1" href="project1.html">
      <img title="Project 1" src="img/projectblur.jpg" alt="Project 1" />
      <img title="Project 1" src="img/project.jpg" alt="Project 1" />
      <span class="openoverlay">Click</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS looks like that:

```
.moodlegrid{
    li{
        a{
            position: relative;
            display:block;
            width: 100%;
            img:nth-child(1){
                display:block;
            }
            img:nth-child(2){
                display: none;
            }
            span{
                display:none;
            }
        }
        a:hover{    
            img:nth-child(2){
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 100;
                top:0;
                left:0;
            }
            span{
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                text-align:center;
                top: 37%;
                left: 28%;
                z-index:101;
                @include border-radius(5px, 5px);
                @include box-shadow(black 2px 2px 10px);
            }
        }
    }
}

img{
    width:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto !important;
}
```

On mouseover a second image as well as a button should float centered on top of the first image. Problem is if the viewport changes the recent version doesn't work anymore and the button isn't centered. The following article on CSS-tricks had a promising solution:

[Centering in the unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

The demo worked fine:

[Centering in the unknown demo](http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/AdJDe)

But it utilizes inline-block elements which makes it difficult to layer images and show on top of them a centered button in the end - the elements are displayed after each other when the display:inline-block property is set. There is also the problem that in contrast to my HTML the demo aligns a child object towards a parent.

Is there a way to apply the mentioned technique to my problem, or is there a maybe even better suiting approach? Best regards Ralf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you rightly, you're almost there I think.

`<a>` needs to be `position: relative;`

`<span>` needs to be `position: absolute;`

On the `<span>` if you set a specific width, and apply:

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px /* Half of the height */
margin-left: -50px; /* Half of the width */
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjcCf

Does that solve what you're trying to do?

Comment: You may want to adjust the width and height to be something more reasonable for the `Click` text. Here is an example that uses `50px` for the width and `20px` for that text. It also parses the LESS. Feel free to leverage any of it for your answer if you'd like. http://jsfiddle.net/kCVzr/1/

Comment: Thanks that worked! I've just exchanged the px values with rem but aside that everything works fine. Your solution has the advantage that it is utilising general properties and nothing like vertical-align which might lead into crossbrowser trouble. So the only thing left to do for me is to adjust button size as well as margin values within media queries. Cool thanks again for the fast help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi is this what look like

html

```
<div>
    <h1><span>button</span></h1>
    <img src="imageSample.jpg" alt="" />    
</div>
```

css

```
div {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
div img {
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
}
div h1 {
    width:100px;
    margin:auto;
}
div h1 span {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    top:200px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CX5Dn/4/)

note: *scroll fiddle so you can see the effect*

Comment: hm if i scale down the window in your fiddle and the image resizes the button isn't keeping its centered position. In your example the span is placed 200px beneath the top border so on smaller images sizes the button is wandering downwards.